# Datetime availability showing wrong results in Php

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I have a shop open and close time and I want to show two things
1) create a time slot of every 30 minutes
2) And match with the database, whether timeslot is booked or available

Here is my database

Table name - **usr_bookng**

```
id      shop_id     date                start_time      end_time
1       4           11-07-2019          10:00:00        11:30:00
```

I tried with the following code, it's creating time slot properly but showing timeslot status wrong, it's showing me following

result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 10:00
            [end] => 10:30
            [status] => availiable
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 10:30
            [end] => 11:00
            [status] => availiable
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 11:00
            [end] => 11:30
            [status] => booked
        )
}
```

Problem is this, only third-time slot showing booked, all three-time-slot should be booked,where is my wrong
Here is my code

```
$duration="30";
        $start="10:00AM";
        $end="07:00PM";
        $start = new DateTime($start);
        $end = new DateTime($end);
        $start_time = $start->format('H:i');
        $end_time = $end->format('H:i');
        $i=0;

        while(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time)){
    $start = $start_time;
    $end = date('H:i',strtotime('+'.$duration.' minutes',strtotime($start_time)));
    $start_time = date('H:i',strtotime('+'.$duration.' minutes',strtotime($start_time)));
    $i++;
    if(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time)){
        $time[$i]['start'] = $start;
        $time[$i]['end'] = $end;
    }

    $todayDate = date('d-m-Y');
    if(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time)){
        $time[$i]['start'] = $start;
        $time[$i]['end'] = $end;
        }

        $query=$this->db->query("select `id` from `usr_booking` where date = '$todayDate' and 
        (( `start_time` >= '$start' AND `start_time` <= '$start' ) || 
        (`end_time` >= '$end' AND `end_time` <= '$end'))");

        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
            {
                $rows = $query->result_array();
                $time[$i]['status'] = 'booked';
            }
        else
        {
                    $rows = $query->result_array();
                    $time[$i]['status'] = 'availiable';
        }
```

Comment: How is this in any way related to "rest" or "datetime"? What have you tried to debug your problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase: i tried a lot, i think something is wrong with my query or loop

Comment: So your logic is not working right ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: Yes you are right sir,dont know where i am wrong ?

Comment: According to your table structure how you are deciding when the shop will be available or blocked ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: its "booked" not "blocked", we can check status of availiablity with database,suppose if shop is book for 11:30am to 12:00am then slot of 11:30 to 12:00 should show as "booked" , rest slots showing availiablity status

Comment: Are the time formats string? If so, I think you can't compare them, you can consider using time format in your database

Comment: @sh4dowb: okay,can you write code(change/correction in my code) so i can implement in my side

Comment: @snehapathak In which table you have this `"booked"` status as it is not there in your `usr_bookng` table structure

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: you are right there is no status in table, i want to use this as static word (booked or availiable )

Comment: You didn't get me right, my question is how you are deciding like this slot is available and this is blocked ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I think there's a session from 10 AM to 7 PM, each 30 mins and he's checking the DB for bookings to see if the sessions are booked

Answer (score 0):

I think your columns are string. You should change your columns to TIME, and query your times as TIME.

Run this for one time, or, you can change `start_time` and `end_time` columns from phpMyAdmin to TIME

```
 ALTER TABLE usr_bookng MODIFY start_time TIME ;
 ALTER TABLE usr_bookng MODIFY end_time TIME ;
```

And for your query;

```
 $query=$this->db->query("select `id` from `usr_booking` where date = '$todayDate' and 
 (( `start_time` >= CAST('$start' AS TIME) AND `start_time` <= CAST('$start' AS TIME) ) || 
 (`end_time` >= CAST('$end' AS TIME) AND `end_time` <= CAST('$end' AS TIME) ))");
```

But I also think you have a logic error in your query, fixing that, final query should be:

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT `id`  FROM `usr_booking` WHERE date = '$todayDate'  AND
( `start_time` <= CAST('$start' AS TIME)  AND `end_time` >= CAST('$end' AS TIME) )");
```

Comment: showing me same result, only third slot showing booked not first three

Comment: @snehapathak check the updated answer, it works for me, I guess: https://imgur.com/ngPkULz

Comment: still not working properly,first slot showing availiable and second and third showing booked but first slot also should showing as booked